# How to use jQuery or JavaScript to filter out results above a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

```
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="100000" max="750000" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
```

This is my slider code that outputs a value below

```
<div id="sliderValue">
<p>Max Value £</p>
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
</div>
```

The value is controlled by the following JS

```
function updateTextInput(val) {
document.getElementById('textInput').value=val;
}
```

I need to create a function that hides the following code block when the .plot-price is greater than the value in #sliderValue.

```
<div class="plot-item col-xs-12 four">
 <div class="plot-img">
  <img src="img/mobile/overview-img.jpg" class="img-border img-responsive">
 </div>
 <div class="plot-details">
  <h2 class="plot-location">Cornwall</h2>
  <p class="plot-number">Plot 5</p>
  <ul>
   <li class="bedrooms">4 bedrooms</li>
   <li  class="plot-price">255995</li>
   <li  class="plot-view"><a href="plot-page.html"> View Plot</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="plot-status">Sold</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help and apologies for any formatting/ question mistakes (first time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a filtering page, if so try

```
function updateTextInput(val) {
    $('#textInput').val(val);
    $('.plot-item').hide().filter(function () {
        return val >= +$(this).find('.plot-price').text()
    }).show();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/suc7feqg/)

Comment: Thanks for your help this has sorted the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Add a id to your block!

```
function updateTextInput(val) {
    $('#textInput').val(val);
    if(val < $('.plot-price').val())
    {
        $('#yourid').fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Also you should not use the onchange-Attribute. Split up your source code!
HTML:

```
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" id="myInputRange" min="100000" max="750000">
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
<div class="plot-item col-xs-12 four">
    <!-- Other code -->
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#myInputRange').change(function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    $('#textInput').val(value);
    if(value < $('.plot-price').val())
    {
        $('#yourid').fadeOut();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#yourid').fadeIn();
    }
}
```